# Ubuntu bonjour name server

Tags: ubuntu, bonjour, avahi, netatalk

Is there a way to have my remote server talking to my mac via bonjour?

Avahi and netatalk are configured and ready using afp.

Tried with opnvpn without success. Also tried with the dns-sd server setup but I'm confused...

FYI: Root Server with Ubuntu 14.04 and a static IP

Answer (score 0):

What type of interface did you use in OpenVPN?

You should use the TAP (Layer2 VPN) interface in OpenVPN since bonjour doesn't work over Layer3 networks.

Comment: Tried it with TAB but couldn't get it to work as expected... Maybe you know a good tutorial? The think is I don't know how to get it working with only one network interface on the server.

Comment: Make sure you bridge your interface on your Ubuntu server. See : [link](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections) For the OpenVPN config see [link](http://www.supinfo.com/articles/single/183-setup-openvpn-server-tap-behind-an-asa)

Comment: Thank you for the two articles. I still don't get how I have to configure my bridge ... I just have one static ip for my server to communicate to the world. There is no 192.168.X.X ip or any other interface. So do I need to bridge it with my 176.X.X.X ip and gateway and stuff?